# PyPI why do I need to pip --upgrade twice?

Tags: pip, pypi

Whenever I publish a new version of my package, I always have to run the upgrade command twice. The first time I run it is says "already satisfied."

```
pip install gorpyter --upgrade

"Requirement already up-to-date: gorpyter in 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.1.5)"


$pip install gorpyter --upgrade

Collecting gorpyter
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages... 0.1.6
```

When you tell it to upgrade and it says *you're up to date* that is very misleading.

---

Is there something analogous to `brew update` that I can run in order to prevent this?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Possible causes: caching, multiple sources, multiple DNS results for the server, ... Please find the root cause and possibly submit a report to https://github.com/pypa/pip

Comment: This is also happening from the terminal, `pip install -U <pkg>` needs to be run twice currently before the updated package is found.

Comment: I put a ticket in: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7097